# Is it correct to have a Socket listening on a port within an ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I have a Winform Desktop C# client.

Its sole purpose is to send jpegs (1 at a time) to my web server.

I was initially using [Web Services].

When the byte array was received in the [web method] the bytes were saved to a static byte array variable to be used elsewhere within the web site. In essence whenever these bytes were accessed the user was retrieving the very latest jpeg uploaded.

To quicken the process of byte array upload I created an eternal Winform C# app on the web server.  At the moment I receive the byte arrays and I save them to the hard drive (so I know that part is working).

I still want to save and access the byte array as the static variable in my main web site.

I know I could port the socket app into my asp.net application.

But, is this acceptable to do or will it cause complications further down the line?

If acceptable can I initiate the socket listening code in the app_startup event in my global.asax page or wil that too cause issues? I will be trying it anyway.

thanks

Comment: What was wrong with transmitting the file via the web method? Seems like a good method.

Comment: @usr invoking a web service with byte[] parameter requires the array be converted to text(json/xml). A better way would be to accept binary POST requests from client (like stream in WCF).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. The reason I changed was because of speed. the continuous calls from client to [web method] was slow in comparison to sockets.

Comment: @L.B Hi, thanks for your comment. Do you mean creating a webclient object within my desktop app and putting that in say like a timer?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson No like file uploading to a web site. just POSTing the binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to switch away from "web methods" because of performance. Try switching to:

1. A binary HTTP post request (easy)
2. WCF with a binding that supports efficient binary transmission (more involved due to setup)

Don't open your own socket because there are easier solutions available. Opening a socket will also cause trouble when the application pool recycles (in that case two worker processes will be running at the same time for a brief period).

Comment: thanks for that pitfall you mentioned.  My main goal is speed of upload and response time back to the client. I will try both to see what works for me but what would you recommend for speed.  Going by the 'efficient binary transmission' description it would seem to be WCF?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson the speed will be dominated by memcpy and network transfer in both cases. They will compare similarly. Use whatever makes more sense in your case. I'd guess that HTTP is slightly less overhead than WCF.